# Erro no BD/lista

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Eu estava seguindo um tutorial de como fazer CRUD, mas apareceu um erro para mim (no tutorial está ok)

Como faço para resolver isso?

```
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_Madicamentos);
    registerForContextMenu(lista);


    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            Medicamentos medicamentoEscolhido = (Medicamentos) adapter.getItemIdAtPosition(position);

            Intent i = new Intent(CadastroActivity.this, FormularioActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("medicamento-escolhido", medicamentoEscolhido);
        }
    });

    lista.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() { //clique longo, para selecionar a linha
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            medicamento = (Medicamentos)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Sobre o erro:**
Na linha

```
Medicamentos medicamentoEscolhido = (Medicamentos) adapter.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
```

Ele dá o erro:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'long' to 'com.example.(...).Medicamentos'
```

E dá a sugestão de que medicamentoEscolhido seja do tipo long.

Como eu resolvo isso? Obrigadaa

Comment: você precisa ver se o método getItemIdAtPosition retorna o objeto medicamentos, pelo nome dele eu diria que ele está retornando só o Id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O nome do método está escrito errado.

Não deve ser `getItemIdAtPosition()` e sim`getItemAtPosition()`.

`getItemIdAtPosition()` retorna um `long`, que é o ID do item.

`getItemAtPosition()` retorna o item, que pode ser convertido (*cast*) para `Medicamentos`.

Comment: Ahh, realmente estava errado, muito obrigada. Agora, está dando outro erro, no segundo trecho do código. Vou postar abaixo

Comment: Outro erro, outra pergunta. Desculpe, são regras da casa.

Comment: Para aceitar esta resposta clique no "v" que aparece abaixo do número, do lado esquerdo da postagem. É a forma como o site funciona.

Comment: Ah sim, mesmo sobre o mesmo código? É erro no segundo trecho que mandei rs

Comment: Mesmo sobre o mesmo código, as perguntas e respostas são pontuais. Isso ajuda na organização do site.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigada ^^